# Why doesn't ''var=value echo $var'' emit value?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Wanted to validate my understanding of why these situations behave differently:

I think #1 happens because the assignment and echo run as a single command in the shell and $SOME_VAR is not set when echo executes (shell expands all variables before execution).

```
#1
$ unset SOME_VAR
$ SOME_VAR=abcdef  echo $SOME_VAR # prints nothing
```

I think #2 happens because the assignment and echo run as two separate commands in the same shell and $SOME_VAR is set in the shell when echo executes.

```
#2
$ unset SOME_VAR
$ SOME_VAR=abcdef   ; echo $SOME_VAR
abcdef
```

**I don't understand why #3 happens**.

```
#3
$ unset SOME_VAR
$ SOME_VAR=abcdef   ./test.sh # prints abcdef 
abcdef
```

I think #4 happens because assignment and execution of shell script execute as two different commands in the parent shell and the child shell that executes commands in test.sh does not inherit SOME_VAR (since there is no export statement).

```
#4
$ unset SOME_VAR
$ SOME_VAR=abcdef   ; ./test.sh # prints nothing
```

test.sh contains:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo $SOME_VAR
```

Comment: To understand what's happening, you can look at what variables are available in the environment a script is running in; if you add `env | grep 'SOME_VAR'` to `test.sh`, you'll see what's different.

Comment: Mostly, #3 adds `SOME_VAR` to the environment of the subprocess, but #4 doesn't. If you change #4 to `export SOME_VAR=abcdef; ./test.sh`, it'll print the value.

Answer (score 3):

Example 1 happens because variable expansion happens first. The order of events in this case is:

1. Expand `$SOME_VAR` (to an empty string)
2. Set `SOME_VAR` to `abcdef`
3. Call `echo` (with no args because `$SOME_VAR` expanded to an empty string)

Example 2 happens, as you say, because the commands are run separately.

Example 3 happens because `SOME_VAR` is set to `abcdef` prior to calling `./test.sh`, and is part of the environment that `./test.sh` is run in. This is actually the purpose of the idiom `VAR=value command`. You want `command` to be able to use `VAR`, but you don't necessarily want every other command or subshell to see it.

Example 4 happens because `SOME_VAR` is a local variable in the current shell and has not been `export`-ed so that subshells can use it.

An Example 5 would then be:

```
unset SOME_VAR
export SOME_VAR=abcdef ; ./test.sh # prints abcdef
```